# How to assign click event to every svg element in d3js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have added nine rectangles in a svg element. How do i add click event to each one?

```
var nodeValues = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

var colors = ["aqua", "darkblue", "black", "red", "green", "gray", "navy", "orange", "teal"];

var main = d3.select("#main");

var svg = main.append("svg")
    .data(nodeValues)
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300);

var elementAttr = function (index) {
    return {
        x: (index % 3) * 100,
        y: Math.floor((index / 3)) * 100,
        width: 95,
        height: 95
    }
}

for (var index in nodeValues) {
    var rect = svg.append("rect")
        .attr(elementAttr(index))
        .style("fill", "red" );
}
```

Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjdhama/z7Y9X/7/).

**UPDATE** : I wish to change attributes like width of rectangle on a click event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for (var index in nodeValues) {
    var rect = svg.append("rect")
        .attr(elementAttr(index))
        .style("fill", "red" )
        .on('click', function(d,i) {
            // handle events here
            // d - datum
            // i - identifier or index
            // this - the `<rect>` that was clicked
        });
}
```

Comment: i tried using `.click` but i doesn't seem to work. Can you post working jsfiddle link.

Comment: I tried changing attributes of `<rect>` inside anonymous function as `this.attr("width", 100)`. It didn't work.

Comment: you might wanna use `d3.select(this).attr("width", 100)` instead of `this.attr("width", 100)`
Also, if you want to improve your code a little bit, you should use the enter-update-exit pattern, check out http://jsfiddle.net/z7Y9X/11/

Comment: Great @VinhTran that works!! And surely i'll use enter-update-exit pattern from now on.

Comment: Thanks @stephen-thomas for documenting the callback - commenting 'this - the `<rect>` that was clicked' is so much easier to understand than 'The specified listener is invoked with the context and arguments determined by the caller' from the documentation. :)

Answer (score 3):

I've refactored your code to be more D3-like -- in particular, you don't need a loop if you use D3's selections and data matching. The code then looks like this:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(nodeValues).enter().append("rect")
    .each(function(d) {
        var attrs = elementAttr(d);
        d3.select(this).attr(attrs);
    })
    .style("fill", rectColor);
```

Adding the click handler is just an additional statement at the end of this:

```
    .on("click", function() {
        d3.select(this).attr("width", 120);
    });
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z7Y9X/15/).

Answer (score 2):

I gave a vote to Stephen's answer but it's actually just missing one part - instead of .click, it's

```
.on("click", function(d){...
```

Here's some [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on). Also, I've jacked Mike's example of [zooming with circles](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680999) in order to implement the binder listener. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5geLS/) that shows it.

Hope that helps!